# Start android activity from cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, cordova-plugins

I know this may is a duplicate question, i have tried all answers from stack, but non has a complete answer.

Most answers just give how to start an activity but no hints how to configure activity in Android Manifest file and where to save activity layout and manifest file.

**Can anyone please give a complete code structure to start an activity from cordova plugin.**

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is the complete steps to start an activity from a cordova plugin

**1. Install Plugman to create plugin**

```
npm install -g plugman
```

**2. Create cordova plugin using plugman**

```
plugman create --name PluginName --plugin_id com.example.sample.plugin --plugin_version 0.0.1
```

N.B : plugin id never start with Uppercase

Now PluginName directory will be created. Plugin structure will be

> PluginName/
>
> |- plugin.xml
>
> |- src/
>
> |- www/PluginName.js

**3. Add android platform to plugin**

```
plugman platform add --platform_name android
```

Now plugin structure will be

> PluginName/
>
> |- plugin.xml
>
> |- src/android/PluginName.java
>
> |- www/PluginName.js

**4. Now create a java file named *NewActivity.java* in *src/android* directory**

This activity will be shown using our plugin.

**NewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sample.plugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String package_name = getApplication().getPackageName();
        setContentView(getApplication().getResources().getIdentifier("activity_new", "layout", package_name));
    }
}
```

**5. Now create layout file *activity_new.xml* in *src/android* directory**

This is the layout file for our new activity

**activity_new.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.sample.plugin.NewActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="New Activity"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**6. Now edit *PluginName.java* in *src/android***

Now we need to handle the request and start our new activity.

**PluginName.java**

```
package com.example.sample.plugin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PluginName extends CordovaPlugin {

    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        if(action.equals("new_activity")) {
            this.openNewActivity(context);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void openNewActivity(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
        this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**7. Now edit *PluginName.js* in *www* directory**

Now create new method to call to start our new activity.

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

function plugin() {

}

plugin.prototype.new_activity = function() {
    exec(function(res){}, function(err){}, "PluginName", "new_activity", []);
}

module.exports = new plugin();
```

**8. Now edit plugin.xml**

Now we need to specify our files to plugin and make necessary changes in cordova AndroidManifest.xml file

**plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="com.example.sample.plugin" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>PluginName</name>
    <js-module name="PluginName" src="www/PluginName.js">
        <clobbers target="PluginName" />
    </js-module>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="PluginName">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.example.sample.plugin.PluginName" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
            <activity android:label="New Activity" android:name="com.example.sample.plugin.NewActivity"></activity>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml"></config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/PluginName.java" target-dir="src/com/example/sample/plugin" />
        <source-file src="src/android/NewActivity.java" target-dir="src/com/example/sample/plugin" />
        <source-file src="src/android/activity_new.xml" target-dir="res/layout"/>
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

**9. Now create a cordova project**

```
cordova create CordovaProject com.example.sample.cordovaproject "Cordova App"
```

**10. Add android platform to your cordova project**

```
cordova platform add android
```

**11. Now add your plugin**

```
cordova plugin add your-plugin-local-path
eg: cordova plugin add "C:\PluginName"
```

**12. Add a button to *index.html* in *www* directory**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
            <button id = "new_activity">New Activity</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**13. Add click handler for new button in *index.js* in *www/js* directory**

When our button is clicked, we will call our plugin method to start our new activity

**index.js**

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        document.getElementById("new_activity").addEventListener("click", new_activity);
    }
};

app.initialize();

function new_activity() {
    PluginName.new_activity();
}
```

**14. Now run this app in android phone**

```
cordova run android
```

If all these steps are success and when we click *New Activity* button, our new activity will show up.

Comment: where did you get "SmartHomePlugin"

Comment: @HKumar sorry, it was a typo error. It should be PluginName. Thanks.

Comment: Could you guide me how to add success and callback method to this  activity

Comment: After finalizing plugin you need to run this command : 
plugman createpackagejson "path of your plugin"

Comment: I did all the previous steps, and i succeed. but still i don't know how to import it in my ionic 4 project. I don't know what import statement should i write to be able to use the plugin. anyone can help me please?

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. But didn't understand what is the use of point 7. If I remove it from my project, all the things still work and the new activity is launched.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this plugin

```
cordova plugin add sevensky-cordova-plugin-intent
```

Usage :

```
    document.getElementById("btn_device_name").addEventListener("click", test);

    function test() {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.name = "Ahmad"; //bundle string extra 1 string
        obj.family = "Aghazadeh"; //bundle string extra 2
        intentPlugin.startActivity("com.sevensky.test", "TestActivity", JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
```

Comment: How do i import intentPlugin in my Js file?