# Android java can't invoke a function from another class. How to do it?

Tags: android, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm trying to call a function to stop the Google VR player from another class. But each time I got this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.thevrplugin.cordovapluginvrplayer.MediaLoader.pause()' on a null object reference

I think that I'm calling it in the wrong way, how would you do it? Maybe it's just private / public / protected modifier mess?

Ps. you can find the **demo project** here: https://github.com/StarStep/cordova-vr-help.git

So the class which has the functions is this:

```
package com.thevrplugin.cordovapluginvrplayer;

...

public class VrVideoActivity extends GvrActivity {
    
    private static final String TAG = "VrVideoActivity";
    private static final int EXIT_FROM_VR_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    private GvrView gvrView;
    private Renderer renderer;
    private VideoUiView uiView;
    protected MediaLoader mediaLoader;
    private ControllerManager controllerManager;
    private Controller controller;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mediaLoader = new MediaLoader(this);

        gvrView = new GvrView(this);
        gvrView.setRenderTargetScale(.5f);
        renderer = new Renderer(gvrView);
        gvrView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        gvrView.setRenderer(renderer);
        setContentView(gvrView);
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        recreate();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mediaLoader.pause();
        controllerManager.stop();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

and then it's called from this

```
public class VrPlayer extends CordovaPlugin {
    
    private String play(Context context, JSONArray args) throws JSONException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, VrVideoActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        JSONObject options = args.getJSONObject(0);
        intent.putExtra("src", options.getString("src"));
        intent.putExtra("displayMode", 0);
        intent.putExtra("inputFormat", 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        return "Ok!";
    }

    private String pause(Context context, JSONArray args) throws JSONException {
        (new VideoActivity()).onPause();
        return "true";
    }        
}
```

Comment: try to make them both public

Comment: tried and got even more trouble. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: I highly recommend you open a book. You're going against the Android Framework now and many programming principles

Comment: @ZUNJAE Thanks you will surely do once I got more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making the reference variable and the function static.

```
protected MediaLoader mediaLoader;  ---> protected static MediaLoader mediaLoader;
private String pause(Context contex... ---> public static void myPause()
```

and then i were able to call it just like this: `VrVideoActivity.myPause();`

Answer (score 1):

`Activities` are instantiated by the Android framework. In order to call methods in a `Activity` you'll need a reference to that activity, but that will probably result in [memory leak](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Please review [Start android activity from cordova plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40375555/295004)

You'll have to have your VrVideoActivity handle all UI/UX behavior and then return back to your Cordova WebApp. You'll need to understand Java and Android development especially the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: I already got the Activity and can close and open it. About the memory leak will check it later. For now I would like to be able to stop the video...I'm preparing a demo, will add the link later to the question if you want to give a closer look. Thanks