# How to import and use custom cordova plugin in ionic 4 project

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins

I did all the required steps to create new cordova plugin as mentioned in the below question and I succeed:

[Start android activity from cordova plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375555/start-android-activity-from-cordova-plugin)

I ran the following command `cordova plugin ls` and I got the following result:

> com.example.sample.plugin 0.0.1 "PluginName"

So my plugin is added to my project.

But still I am not able to import it in the .ts file my ionic 4 project. What import statement should I write to be able to use the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// at the top of your file outside of any class definitions
declare var cordova: any;

cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.function();
```

I believe it takes the plugin name from the  tag, for example:

```
<js-module src="www/sign-in-with-apple.js" name="SignInWithApple">
```

Comment: didn't work. should i add cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.function(); in home.js file in the assets folder for example?

Comment: @AliWehbi no what i meant was you can call your plugin like this. you add `declare var cordova: any;` at the top of your calling file, and then wherever you want to call your function you use `cordova.plugins.YourPluginName.yourFunctionName();`. `YourPluginName` should match what is in the tag that describes your plugin in the config.xml.